# When should you use AWS SageMaker GroundTruth (SMGT) vs AWS Sagemaker Augmented AI (A2I)?

Tags: data-annotations, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ground-truth

I'm working on building an annotation workflow for my data science team. I see there are conflicting AWS products and it's not clear which one to use for what purpose.